# Avro as serialization protocol for http sockets consumed by different language clients

Tags: design-patterns, avro

I have a socket service that pushes messages in JSON format. A typical message looks this way:

```
{
    "messageType": "UserRecievedMessage",
    "version": "1.0",
    "body": {
        "sender_user_id": 123456,
        "ts": "1527624150",
        "message": "Hi, man!"
    }
}
```

Client (JavaScript / Java / Python / PHP) receives json, reads **messageType**, **version** fields and applies correct parser to read message. Single socket channel can push messages of different types.

I'm looking for a more round wheel than I have today. Can I use Avro?

Why Avro?

- All my clients would be able to use some Avro library to read data serialized in avro instead of plain json.
- evolving schema
- I can generate php / java / JavaScript classes for my clients so they would work with higher abstraction layer and there will be less chance to break the contract.

My concerns:

- can I generate classes in php / javascript / java / swift from avro schema?
- do these languages have proper support for Avro? It would be hard to test all corner cases for every language in advance.
- how should I correctly imitate "envelope"? A client would still have to read  "messageType" and then take body field bytes and deserialize it to the concrete class.